# Can land breezes be an example of perpetual motion?

Tags: thermodynamics, perpetual-motion, convection, thermal-conduction

Since perpetual motion refers to a never-ending motion with no external energy provided whatsoever, can land breezes or sea breezes be an example? Or perhaps even trade winds, since this, I believe, is a pattern that keeps going due to natural convection and the Coriolis effect, right?

I do know perpetual motion is more of a hypothetical concept, but I'm not sure how this cannot be considered as an example.

Comment: This is a fine question asking about a physics concept in good faith. I don’t see why it has down votes. We down vote bad quality questions, not questions that misunderstand physics concepts.

Comment: I have hidden a comment which should have been posted as an answer, and a number of replies to it. Please use comments to clarify and improve the post they are attached to. To answer a question, post an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not an example of perpetual motion.

Both kinds of wind are driven by temperature differences (the trade winds by temperature differences between different latitudes, which in turn are caused by the angle of the ground relative to the incoming solar radiation; land-sea wind systems by the temperature difference between land and sea surface in the course of the day).

Over a warmer surface the air is heated and rises up (as warm air has a lower density). This reduces the air pressure and air is "sucked in" (actually pushed in by the higher pressure) – causing a wind. The convection cell is then closed by the converse effect higher in the atmosphere (where the air rises up to the pressure is increased and the air is pushed to where, over cold surfaces air is pushed down).

So, the natural convection is ultimately driven by heat energy supplied by the sun. As usual with thermal energy, only temperature *differences* can be converted to mechanical energy. So, e.g. when the surface temperatures between land and sea have equilibrated over the course of the night, the land-sea wind will cease.

Coriolis force does not really matter for the discussion. It changes the direction of the winds, but it does not accelerate the winds on its own (as the Coriolis force is perpendicular to the velocity, it does not change the absolute value of the velocity).

**What happens when regarding the sun as energy source as part of the system**

This does not work out either. The catch is the second law of thermodynamics. To extract work the thermal energy from the sun we need a second heat bath (namely, the cold almost isotropic space!). So we can't just take the sun as part of the isolated system. If so we have to take the *entire* universe as our system (because we need the rest of the universe as "entropy dump"!). Also, this process will not be reversible, as processes that couple to a heat bath can only be reversible, if the temperature differences during heat exchange are infinitesimal (exactly what happens in the Carnot cycle – we heat and cold our work medium isentropically in the parts of the cycle where we isolate the medium from the heat bath, and then have a quasistatic isothermic expansion/compression when connected to the heat bath).

Comment: The main point is that the source of energy is the sun, which will, eventually, in some billions of years, run out of fuel. We don't have to worry about that, because we, including earth, will be gone at that time in the far future. Still, it is not *perpetual motion* in the strict sense.

Comment: It wouldn't be perpetual motion in the sense of the question even if the sun supplied energy forever, since the sun is an external energy supply to the wind systems (and the question defined perpetual motion as not having an external energy supply).

Comment: Ah, if you formally  include a sun with a supposed endless energy resource in the system you are looking at, it *would* be a perpetual motion, won't it? Beside, the whole of the universe is, in some way, a Perpetuum mobile; if will move till the end of time, as the end of motion *will* be the end of time.

Comment: I see, that does make sense. But if I exclude the part of my question that asks about an 'external energy' source, can this be a rough example? As @GyroGearloose said, the Sun can be considered as an endless source, if it's included in this entire isolated system, right?

Comment: Sun is not an endless source, once the nuclear fuel is burned it will go out.

Comment: @Mei, I didn't say "the sun can be considered as an endless source", someone (I don't bother to find the quote) suggested that the sun was an eternal source of energy flow, and I simply agreed that ***if that was the case*** it could be included in the system. I guess you won't take "No" for an answer with a bounty?

Comment: @Mel Like burning a gasoline in an engine is not a perpetual motion, similarly wind effects due to Sun heating which happens because it burns nuclear fuel,- is also not a perpetuum mobile for 2 reasons : a) Sun's thermonuclear reactions will end at some point b) Energy flow in a Sun-Earth system is one-way,- it heats atmosphere causing increased entropy in it. Later this heat is dissipated into outer-space. For system to be a true perpetual motion,- energy used for a motion must be returned back into a system for a repeated re-usage. It would correspond returning winds energy back to Sun.

Comment: @Mel But you can't do so, because you have been used some wind energy for achieving other tasks,- pushing sails, turning wind turbines, etc. So this system thermodynamicaly can't be a perpetual motion in any way.